# install rpm packages and dealing with dependencies

Tags: linux, rpm

I am trying to install apt-get on centos.

```
wget http://pkgs.repoforge.org/apt/apt-0.5.15lorg3.2-1.el4.rf.x86_64.rpm
rpm -i apt-0.5.15lorg3.2-1.el4.rf.x86_64.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
    libbeecrypt.so.6()(64bit) is needed by apt-0.5.15lorg3.2-1.el4.rf.x86_64
    libreadline.so.4()(64bit) is needed by apt-0.5.15lorg3.2-1.el4.rf.x86_64
    librpm-4.3.so()(64bit) is needed by apt-0.5.15lorg3.2-1.el4.rf.x86_64
    librpmdb-4.3.so()(64bit) is needed by apt-0.5.15lorg3.2-1.el4.rf.x86_64
    librpmio-4.3.so()(64bit) is needed by apt-0.5.15lorg3.2-1.el4.rf.x86_64
```

Now I can try to download the missing libraries individually, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can try to use a package manager, which will manage the dependencies for you. The problem will be to find the RPM file in a repository, add that repository to your package manager, update the index information of your pack. manager. Looking at that RPM, I think you will be using yum.

Comment: Note that if this an RPM that isn't in the yum repo, you can always do "yum localinstall </path/to/file.rpm>"

Comment: @Corey Henderson - I'm not sure when it happened, but you can now use "yum install <path/to/file.rpm>".  See man yum -> "install"